# Get All Recent Windows For Specfic App

Tags: lineageos, recents-screen

I am running Lineage OS Oreo and as an example the default browser opens all web browser windows as seperate processes/windows.  There is no option to change this that I could find, but it actually seems to run better like this with less slow downs.  I believe they are running in separate processes or threads.  Is there a way to get recent apps for only that process maybe?  I want to see the pictures and not just a list of the past windows.

Comment: "Individual tabs in recent list" is a feature of the default Browser (Jelly), and actually seen as a perk by many LOS users (not me though). Just use a different browser instead.

Comment: @andyYan I am pretty sure they are running on the same thread or process.  Because the browser grinds to a hault when there 10+ tabs for example in Chrome or Samsung browser.

Comment: @AndyYan sorry I am not a developer so I might be using the wrong terms but jelly works well because each window is a separate process in Jelly I believe that is why it works better.  I am having the issue with Chrome and Samsung Browser when I have a bunch of tabs open.  They freeze jelly doesn't.  I like the jelly behavior I just want to be able to see all windows I have open.

Comment: I guess I understood you backwards then... No suggestions I can give, since AFAIK the recent list doesn't work that way.